# Where should I apply programatic layout changes in initialization of Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing an Android Activity, in which I need to make some programatic changes to the layout on initialization.

The activity uses a standard onCreate call which set's up the content view from an XML resource via setContentView(R.layout.main). This works fine. However, I need to change the position of some objects in my code.

When I tried calling object.layout from inside onCreate and onResume, the layout changes never seem to get applied.

Is there someplace else I should be doing this?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navPanel);
    Rect myrect = new Rect();
    rl.getLocalVisibleRect(myrect);
    rl.layout(myrect.left,-120,myrect.right,(myrect.bottom-myrect.top)-120);
```

Comment: please give some code, how do you make the changes ?

Comment: Try pasting the code here for us to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be calling `layout()` yourself. Android handles that. You need to be doing other things to affect your layout change, typically by adjusting the `LayoutParams` for the widget.